# Clang-format not installing

Tags: installation, clang, clang-format

I am trying to install clang-format. I have used:

```
sudo apt install clang-format
```

Which gives me:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done clang-format-10 is already the newest
> version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1). The following packages were automatically
> installed and are no longer required:   docker-scan-plugin
> gir1.2-goa-1.0 graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libamd2 libbtf1
> libbz2-dev libcamd2 libccolamd2 libceres-dev libceres1 libcholmod3
> libcxsparse3 libgflags-dev   libgflags2.2 libgoogle-glog-dev
> libgoogle-glog0v5 libgraphblas3 libgraphics-magick-perl
> libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
> libgraphicsmagick-q16-3   libgraphicsmagick1-dev libklu1 liblcms2-dev
> libldl2 libmetis5 libmongoose2 libnorm-dev libpcap0.8-dev libpgm-dev
> librbio2 libsodium-dev libspqr2 libsuitesparse-dev libumfpack5  
> libwmf-dev libxmlb1 libzmq3-dev ros-foxy-google-benchmark-vendor
> ros-foxy-ompl ros-foxy-urg-c Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 386 not upgraded.
```

However after doing it if I write:

```
clang-format --version
```

What I get is:

```
Command 'clang-format' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install clang-format
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: `clang-format-10 --version`